# How can I detach the file explorer into another window?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Can I somehow detach the file explorer and have it run in a separate program window rather than having it in the sidebar?

Comment: As a short explanation: I think such a setup might be very nice for projects with a large code base if you have a second monitor.

Comment: Don't think this is possible. If it was, you would have already figured out how to do it. But there is [a feature request](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/10121) for detachable tool windows in VS Code.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for this and I didn't find it either.
But I found an alternative way that helped me.
I'm going to share, because maybe it will help you too.

"Open active file in new window"

On Windows and Linux, press CTRL+K, then release the keys and press O (the letter O, not Zero).

On macOS, press CMD+K, then O (without holding CMD).

This will open the active file tab in a new window/instance.

Thus, you can keep the Explorer in one window and manipulate the files in the other.